# Cordova plugin - Javascript receive message from native code

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, sencha-touch-2

As the following documentation here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins

I override an method

```
 @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if ("beep".equals(action)) {
            this.beep(args.getLong(0));
            callbackContext.success();
            return true;
        }
        return false;  // Returning false results in a "MethodNotFound" error.
    }
```

And call it from Javascript like this:

```
cordova.exec(<successFunction>, <failFunction>, <service>, <action>, [<args>]);
```

Above java native code only return an boolean result. How to make it return an string ( or JSON ) and make cordova.exec() receive it ?

p/s: I want to use java native code read a JSON string (List of items) from email. And it will return to Javascript code to render to an list in Sencha Touch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is provided in the documentation page you linked. Check the last code example on the page:

```
private void echo(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
            callbackContext.success(message); //<-THIS LINE
        } else {
            callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
        }
    }
```

According to documentation: "the callbackContext.success() passes the original message string back to JavaScript's success callback as a parameter."

So in JS, if you define success callback function like:

```
function onSuccess(message){
     console.log(message);
}
```

and call it:

```
cordova.exec(onSuccess, ...)
```

It should output contents of the passed `message` string parameter on success.

Comment: Oh. Thanks you. This's my big mistake.